# Series of cell references and value lookups in VBA

Tags: vba

I need a UDF that looks up multiple values from multiple cells.The cells should be found by their offset from the cell that calls the UDF.

What I have so far always results in #value

```
Function Test() As Integer
    Dim OwnCell As Range
    Dim Total As Range
    Dim Val As Integer
    Set OwnCell = Application.ThisCell.Address
    Set Total = OwnCell.Offset(13, -4)
    Val = Worksheets("Blad1").Range(Total).Value
    Test = Val
End Function
```

Managed to make it "work", but it seems incredibly unelegant:

```
Function Test() As Integer
    Dim OwnCell As String
    Dim Total As String
    Dim TotalVal As Integer
    OwnCell = Application.ThisCell.Address
    Total = Range(OwnCell).Offset(1, 1).Address
    TotalVal = Worksheets("Blad1").Range(Total).Value
    Test = Val
End Function
```

Comment: The reason is, on your first you are trying to set a string (the cell Address) to a range. If you remove the `.address` when setting a range it should work as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the cell to return is actually on a different sheet from the one where the UDF is entered then this should work:

```
Function Test() As Integer
    Test = Application.ThisCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
End Function
```